# Is it possible to access the data stored on a HN62304BPC99 ROM?

Tags: synthesizer, rom

The [HN62304BPC99](https://schematicsforfree.com/files/Audio/Products/Musician/R/Roland/Roland%20D-110%20Multi%20Timbral%20Sound%20Module%20-%20Reverb%20SERVICE_NOTES.pdf) appears in a number of Roland synths.

Whilst I can find service manuals & the odd reference to dumping ROM contents, what I cant find as of yet is a way to wire up this chip in a meaningful manner into a custom circuit.

Do these kinds of PCM ROMs have a standard interface? What kind of data bus architecture am I looking at for instance? What pins do what?

Apologies for any glaringly n00bishness surrounding this. I have just been given some & would like to put them to some kind of use.

[image]

Comment: The picture is too fuzy to be able to read some of the pin names for the address bits, but https://www.polynominal.com/roland-d110/Roland-D-110-Service-Manual.pdf says the HN62304BPC99 is a ``4Mbit mask ROM``. The bus architecture looks like it matches a ``4 Mbit (512Kb x 8)`` EEPROM such at the [M27C4001](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/7903.pdf), with the exception that pin 1 is ``NC`` on the HN62304BPC99 mask ROM, whereas on the M27C4001 EEPROM pin 1 is ``Vpp`` (EEPROM programming supply). The HN62304BPC99 is a mask ROM only programmed during manufacture, so read only.

Comment: What is the use case for the HN62304BPC99? Do you just want to read the contents or use it to create your own synth?

Comment: It has to be possible, otherwise it would defeat the point of a ROM.

Comment: @ChesterGillon create my own synth using the chip

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question is it possible to access, read, or dump it;

yes because it 's just a ROM chip, and since it is possible for the system to read it so it can be read out of the system too.

Also, the fact that it's already been dumped confirms it's dumpable.

The interface is just a parallel bus, with address,  chip select and output enable inputs, and data bus for output, like any other standard ROM chip.

Answer (score 2):

It should be no problem, as it appears to be compatible with M27C4001 as @Chester has indicated. This kind of memory, unlike microcontroller flash memory, is not protected in any way.

In my case, I'd just pop it into an inexpensive Willem type EEPROM programmer and read it into a hex file. If you don't have and don't want to buy or borrow such a thing you could wire up an Arduino and a chip or two on a breadboard and write a few lines of code to do a similar thing.

Comment: There is no need to read it in a programmer without a good reason, the contents of these PCM ROMs are already on the Internet. Using the chips themselves in a custom synth is another thing.